# Which server should I go on AWS for deploying a dynamic website with ability to dynamically add new sub domains with mass sharing capabilities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, server, react-fullstack

I am developing a web portal where users can create their own websites which they can publish under my domain (have their own sub domain , say my domain is [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com), I need the new subdomain to be - [www.subdomain.xyz.com/asdf](http://www.subdomain.xyz.com/asdf) ) 
I am using NodeJs
I need to host api, have a database, hosting and file storage capabilities (like Firebase has in 1 console - Hosting, Realtime DB, Cloud storage and Cloud functions or like Azure).
 I need to know if there is any AWS available for my requirements.

Edit-
Let me know how I can ask this question better please. I am new to servers and have only used Firebase.

Comment: First, a subdomain would be newsubdomain.xyz.com. This is a path.
Then, your question is too broad... Can you find compute, database, storage and other services on AWS ? Yes. Does it really help you ? No. Can we do better ? No, you only ask if you can host something like that, you don't have any specific problem. A web factory is pretty common.

Comment: @ClémentDuveau Can you help me narrow my question down? I need hosting, db, storage and api management in 1 service on AWS if it exists. Not multiple, but 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a broad question, here is a broad answer :)
AWS announced a new service which is "elastic beanstalk". You might want to check this.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html

You can also check this https://aws.amazon.com/websites/. AWS has already offered some ways for your issue I think.

Other than that, you can go with an EC2 machine(s) with an elastic IP address, so that you will be sure that your public IP will never change.

Aws also has:

- Network file system(NFS)
- Content delivery network(CDN) - you can save your static files(png etc.)
- Route 53 for your DNS operations

I hope this helps a little.